# How can I test methods that depends heavily on MFC with GTest

Tags: c++, mfc, tdd, googletest

I've started to use GTest (Google Test) for a C++ project I'm working on.  I have one class that depends heavily on MFC (CFile, CObject, CString, etc.).

How can I break the dependencies on MFC (or minimize them) so I don't have to create dummy MFC objects just to run my tests?  I want to test what my methods do not MFC functionnalities.

Here is an example of the kind of method I have to test :

```
// DumpContext class inherits from CDumpContext
void MyClass::Print(DumpContext &dc)
{

    // MyClass::Print real work goes here :
    ...

}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see the problem. If your class descends from an MFC class, you cannot remove that dependency from your project. The way to make sure you test your code and not MFC's is to write the *code in your tests* such that you're testing your code and not MFC's.

Comment: My class don't descends from MFC but uses references and local variables that are MFC classes. In the given example, I have to create a DumpContext prior to call the Print method. To create a CDumpContext (that my method can use), I have to pass a CFile to CDumpContext constructor.  To create a CFile, I need an handle which I creates by calling CreateFile function, etc...  I would prefer just to pass a mock DumpContext to my method instead of using MFC classes to create a "real" CDumpContext.  Does it make more sense now?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand, the fact that MFC lacks interfaces makes it difficult to mock.
As an alternative you can inherit from a dependency and try to make the best out of it.
In your example you can use the already existing CMemFile which doesn't require anything when constructing and lets you access the result.

In other cases you have to invent something similar yourself.

```c
class MyClass
{
public:
    void Print(CDumpContext &dc) {
        dc.DumpAsHex(5592);
        return;
    }
};

TEST(Demo_Test,MyClass)
{
    CMemFile File;
    CDumpContext DumpContext_Stubb(&File);
    MyClass Class;
    Class.Print(DumpContext_Stubb);
    EXPECT_GT(File.GetLength() ,0); // Do some test on the result
}
```